# Power characters in Java

Tags: java, text, rendering, jtextfield

I'm having some problems with text rendering on a JTextField. I would like to print in this field a mathematic expression, with the exponents of powers and the indexes of roots should go to the top of the line, like every power you've ever seen. Besides, I would like the root symbol to extend over the following terms. How can I do that?

Comment: are you usin g JTextField to get some input? or u just want to display something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well with a JLabel you can use an HTML superscript but JTextField does not do HTML. So if you don't need to take input, use a JLabel. It is as simple as `"<html><sup>123</sup></html>"`.

You can still display some characters as superscript in a JTextField through some special UTF characters, the locations of which are:

- `2, 3, 1` in [Latin-1 Supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_%28Unicode_block%29) (`\u00B2`, `\u00B3` and `\u00B9`).
- `0, 4-9` and some symbols in [Superscripts and Subscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscripts_and_Subscripts_%28Unicode_block%29).
- Wikipedia has a pretty complete looking list of other superscripts and subscripts at [Unicode subscripts and superscripts#Other superscript and subscript characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Other_superscript_and_subscript_characters).

Some of what you are asking (like about extending the root symbol) seems a little too much to ask. A JTextField can't do that. I am sure there would be TeX/LaTeX/etc typesetting libraries for Java though if you want real mathematical notation.

Comment: Thank you very much, I needed only 2 and 3. Isn't there any Y superscript?

Comment: I've never seen a Y. : )

Comment: I found some. [Lower case 'y' seems to be in Spacing Modifier Letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacing_Modifier_Letters). There's a character that looks like an uppercase 'Y' but I guess it's a Greek gamma. See my edit which has a link to a list of other characters. : )